# Magento 2: Custom theme no products on listing page

Tags: theme, catalog, magento2.2

I have created **magento 2** custom theme and set that theme as current theme from admin. On frontend no products are found on listing page, search page and home page. I already have sample data.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Please share your code of the custom theme. It might be possible that the error is in your theme.

Comment: Have you ever found the answer to this?